# Two useState in an one function and called the function in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

I need to show monthly data in a Table.

**Expected Logic**

User can change the month, then data should be fetched from server.

**Problem**
I have a handleCalendar function to increase month or decrease month.
then it use useState to set a month and year.
after setCalendar function called in the handleCalendar,
useEffect called by calendar variable, but sometimes it won't remove the previous remaining data .

**My code**

Variables

```
  const [apiData, setData] = React.useState({
    data: [],
    items: 2,
    hasMore: true,
    cursor: todayTimestamp          //to prevent to fetch overlap data.
  });
  const [calendar, setCalendar] = React.useState(null);
```

handleCalender

````
const handleCalender = (arg) => {
    let date = calendar.split("-");
    let year = Number(date[0]);
    let month = Number(date[1]);
    console.log(year, month);

    if (arg === "add") {
      if (calendar === common.getTodayDateForm()) {
        return;
      }
      if (month === 12) {
        year = year + 1;
        month = 1;
        month = common.leadingZeros(month, 2);
        year = String(year);
        setCalendar(year + "-" + month);
        return;
      }
      month = month + 1;
      month = common.leadingZeros(month, 2);
      year = String(year);
      setCalendar(year + "-" + month);
    }
    if (arg === "dec") {
      //TODO increase callender by 1
      if (month === 1) {
        year = year - 1;
        month = 12;
        month = common.leadingZeros(month, 2);

        year = String(year);
        setCalendar(year + "-" + month);
        return;
      }
      month = month - 1;
      month = common.leadingZeros(month, 2);
      year = String(year);
    }
    let lastTimeStamp = common.getTimeStamp();

    setData({ data: [], cursor: lastTimeStamp });
    setCalendar(year + "-" + month);
    return;
  }; 
```

useEffect
```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("cursor in apiData1", apiData.cursor);

    (async () => {
      await fetchData();
    })();
    console.log("cursor in fetchData2", apiData.cursor);

    console.log("에이피아이", apiData);
  }, [calendar]);
```

fetch data
```
  const fetchData = async () => {
    Axios.post("https://naver.com", {
      stations: ["T1219071903", "T1219071904"],
      yearMonth: calendar,
      cursor: apiData.cursor
    }).then((a) => {
      console.log();
      let dataAdded = a.data.data.earningData;
      setData({
        data: [...apiData.data, ...dataAdded],
        pageNumber: apiData.pageNumber + 1,
        cursor: a.data.data.cursor,
        yearMonth: calendar,
        hasMore: a.data.data.hasMore
      });
    });
  };
```

I guess that since setData is not asynchronous,
It would not promise to setData before useEffect called by calendar.

I would like to know what is the best approach to this.
Thank you
````

Comment: **Offtopic**, it is _calendar_, not _calender_. Calender is machine in which paper or cloth is made smooth and glossy by being pressed through rollers.

Comment: @Jax-p Oh I see. I edited the post.